# Ruby Rails NoMethodError in MoviesController#index for sort using SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a Ruby App for reviewing movies. In my movie index view I have a drop down menu which will select the name of the category to sort by and the movie controller contains the following code to display only movies of that genre:

```
@category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
@movies = Movie.where(:category_id => @category_id).("created_at DESC")
```

Movies belong to a category in the database.

Now for some reason I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in MoviesController#index
>
> undefined method `call' for # Did you mean? caller

Whenever I try to sort the movies. This is thrown on the second line of the code above. This worked before I cleared my database, (the categories are still intact) so it might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the bug is the `.("created_at DESC")`, I think you want: `order(created_at: :desc)`

Answer (score 1):

What JP Silvashy said.

Also, you can do:

```
@category = Category.find_by(name: params[:category])
@movies = Movie.where(category: @category).order(created_at: :desc)
```

This assumes `Movie belongs_to :category`.

Or you could just do (unless you're going to use `@category` somewhere else):

```
@movies = Movie.where(category: Category.find_by(name: params[:category])).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Oh boy thank you it works now but for some reason nothing is displayed anymore, do you think you might know why?

Comment: You said you cleared your database? Perhaps there are no movies anymore?

Comment: There are two I added back in so I expected them to show up.

Comment: Do they have the `category` in your `where` clause?